# How to determine the number of fields in the result of select

Tags: python, loops, select

I have function which returns the results from select from database:

```
def print_query_result(con, query):

    con.execute(query)

    for row in con:
         print (row[0], row[1], row[3])
```

functional call:

```
print_query_result(con, 'SELECT  * from table')
```

It works properly, but sometimes I would like change number of fields (via parameter od function) (now it is hardcode like row[0], row[1], row[2]).

But I have problem in building these loop in loop.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: you can use loop in `row`

Comment: Will you always want the first through `n`th field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
def print_query_result(con, query, nth=3):

    con.execute(query)

    for row in con:
         print(*row[:nth])
```